# Request to add a [bed leveling] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

There are currently about 50 questions containing the words “[leveling](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22leveling%22%20is%3Aq)” or “[levelling](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22levelling%22%20is%3Aq)”. I think it would be helpful to unify them with a tag, but I can't find an appropriate one. Further, several of these questions are tagged with `[heated-bed]` without being about heating, which is somewhat misleading.

Bed leveling is an area in which one may accrue distinct expertise, and as such I would like to suggest a `[bed-leveling]` tag to help experts find and answer questions. The spelling with a single “l” is the more common spelling used on the site and also that used in Marlin's documentation. The tag's ambit could encompass:

1. Mechanical bed-leveling such as manual adjustment of screws and springs
2. Software bed-leveling like the [G29 G-Code command](http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/G029-mbl.html)
3. General Z-axis measurement with a mechanical or inductive probe

The tag could also be applied post-facto to questions about printing problems like poor-adhesion, should the solution be found to involve bed calibration.

Answer (score 2):

There is no tag created for leveling (or levelling, or bed-leveling for that matter). So, I would recommend taking some of your top search results for leveling, of your results, if any have available tags (not all 5 tags have been used) then add/created the [bed-leveling] tag.

Overall, this is a good catch on potentially improving the tagging here on 3DPrinting SE.

Comment: I cannot add tags or edit questions yet, but if you could create the tag I would be happy to make edit suggestions, starting with any posts that would also benefit from grammar or formatting help.

Comment: @IanMackinnon I just added the bed-leveling tag, so it should be available now. Happy editing! :)

Answer (score 1):

As confirmed by [this comment](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255/request-to-add-a-bed-leveling-tag#comment363_256) under the other answer, there is now a [bed-leveling](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bed-leveling) tag, so this meta question should now be marked as:

1. having an accepted answer, to remove it from the unanswered questions list, and;
2. status complete (which has just been done)