# The automatic bed leveling tag is spelt incorrectly

Tags: feature-request, tags

This tag, [automaticbedlevling](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automaticbedlevling), is rather ugly, and has at least three issues:

1. Mis-spelt - missing an "e"
2. It is almost illegible (i.e. difficult to read)
3. No hyphens - shouldn't it be hyphenated, like this: `[automatic-bed-leveling]`?

It only has two questions tagged with it (so far).

For reference, and consistency, see also this ancient question, [Request to add a [bed leveling] tag](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/255/4762) - We don't have [leveling](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leveling), nor [levelling](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/levelling), but we *do* have [bed-leveling](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bed-leveling).

Therefore, I propose changing [automaticbedlevling](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automaticbedlevling) to [automatic-bed-leveling](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automatic-bed-leveling).

Note: I don't believe that it should be abbreviated, or become an acronym, such as `[abl]`, because no one would probably be able to find it (unless they already knew that it existed or it was made into a synonym)... but maybe I am wrong..? That is to say, it seems much more natural to start typing "autom..." when looking for a tag relating to automatic bed leveling - I certainly would *not* type "abl" if looking for the tag.

Answer (score 4):

I have added [automatic-bed-leveling](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automatic-bed-leveling) and retagged the two questions that were using the incorrectly spelt [automaticbedlevling](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automaticbedlevling).

I have also added a synonym [abl](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abl).

Comment: Nice! Thanks for checking this out.

Comment: Nice work! I even didn't know we had an automatic bed levelling tag, no wonder it's just 2 tagged questions... You always see the bed-levelling tag being used. Makes me wonder, maybe we should revisit many questions and change the tag when automatic levelling is meant in the question.

Comment: @0scar - yeah, I was thinking that too... but there's 228 questions to go through! :-)

Comment: @0scar - One question is, should a question about auto-bed levelling be tagged with *both* bed-leveling *and* auto-bed-leveling tags? The more you think about it, the more ramifications or issues you end up thinking about. The most obvious one is: You'll end up having to look up both tags.

Comment: @Greenonline 228 is doable ;-) and not both tags, it may be better to introduce a `automatic` tag instead

Comment: @0scar - if we are thinking about having a question tagged with both an `automatic` (prefix tag) and `bed-leveling` tags, then we had just as well stick with tagging with both `automatic-bed-leveling` and `bed-leveling` tags - because the end result would be the same: two tags. I don't think that having two tags is necessarily a bad idea... `automatic-bed-leveling` would just end up being a subset of `bed-leveling`.

Comment: @Greenonline Tags are limited per question, so it is best to not have to multiple tag questions. It is better for the regulars to retag bed-levelling to automatic-bed-levelling when appropriate.